# Не могу прописать путь к элементу массива в массиве

Tags: java, android, json

Делаю приложение "Погода". Через JSON пытаюсь вытащить 3 элемента: city_name, temp, description. Первые два элемента отображаются без проблем а вот description не работает. Пожалуйста, поясните кто нить, что не так?

//JSON код

```
 {
"data": [
    {
        "rh": 93,
        "pod": "n",
        "lon": 37.61556,
        "pres": 1000.4,
        "timezone": "Europe/Moscow",
        "ob_time": "2020-01-20 18:00",
        "country_code": "RU",
        "clouds": 100,
        "ts": 1579543200,
        "solar_rad": 0,
        "state_code": "48",
        "city_name": "Moscow",
        "wind_spd": 6,
        "last_ob_time": "2020-01-20T18:00:00",
        "wind_cdir_full": "Западный",
        "wind_cdir": "З",
        "slp": 1022,
        "vis": 1.5,
        "h_angle": -90,
        "sunset": "13:41",
        "dni": 0,
        "dewpt": 1,
        "snow": 0,
        "uv": 0,
        "precip": 2.84211,
        "wind_dir": 270,
        "sunrise": "05:41",
        "ghi": 0,
        "dhi": 0,
        "aqi": 14,
        "lat": 55.75222,
        "weather": {
            "icon": "r01n",
            "code": "500",
            "description": "Небольшой дождь"    <---- нужно получить значение.
        },
        "datetime": "2020-01-20:18",
        "temp": 2,
        "station": "UUMO",
        "elev_angle": -35.89,
        "app_temp": -2.9
    }
],
"count": 1
```

}

//Java

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
            String city = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(0).getString("city_name");
            String temp = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(0).getString("temp");
            String description = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("weather").getJSONObject(0).getString("description");
            String weather = String.format("город: %s\nТемпература: %s °C\nНа улице:", city, temp, description);
```

Comment: У вас weather это не массив а объект поэтому и проблема, берите его как объект и вытаскивайте описание

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 String description = 
       jsonObject.getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("weather").getString("description");
```